# Confused regarding active patterns

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

I understand how active patterns can be defined and used in F#, including partial active patterns, and the different sorts of patterns available. E.g.

```
let (|Big|Small|) animal = if animal.IsBig then Big(animal) else Small(animal)
let f = function | Big(_) -> "big" |Small(_) -> "small
```

However, I'm confused regarding using active patterns and discriminated unions in `let` bindings, arguments, and other places. For example, the MSDN has the following code:

```
let GetSubstring1 (Slice(p0, p1, text)) = 
    printfn "Data begins at %d and ends at %d in string %s" p0 p1 text
    text.[p0..p1]
```

Which confuses me a bit.

A specific issue. Let's say I have the discriminated union,

```
type Union = A of int * int | B of int
```

Can I somehow make a function that accepts only `Union.A`, e.g.

```
let f (A(a, b)) = a + b
```

In this situation, it tells me there are unmatched patterns. Is there a way to satisfy it?

Comment: The issue is more general than just active patterns – **all** pattern matching may occur in many more contexts than is immediately apparent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted by @ildjarn, this applies to all patterns. They can appear in cases of the `match` clause (and in `function` which is similar), but also in the parameter declaration of `let` bound function and even in the `let` value binding.

The key difference is that with `let`, you only want to use *complete* patterns that will always succeed. This is not needed for `match` or `function`, because there are multiple clauses, so if the first one fails, the matching can continue and try the next one.

For example, the following *complete* pattern takes `int` and returns it as a `string`:

```
let (|AsString|) (n:int) = n.ToString()
```

Here are some ways how you can use it:

```
let (AsString s) = 42         // Defines a value 's' of type string
match 3 with AsString s -> s  // Returns a value "3" of type string
let convert (AsString s) = s  // Defines a function 'int -> string'
let convert = function AsString s -> s  // Same as the previous line
```

**EDIT**: To answer your second question, if you use `let` with an *incomplete* pattern (i.e. that accepts only a single case of a discriminated union) then you get a compiler warning and the code may fail at runtime (if you call it with the other discriminated union case):

```
let f (A(a, b)) = a + b      // This gives compile-time warning
f (B 42)                     // This will fail at runtime
```

If you need to define a function that works only one of the cases, then you need to define a separate type.

```
type AInfo = int * int 
type Union = A of AInfo | B of int
```

Then you can write a function that will only take `AInfo` (but you can still work with `Union` in places where both options represent a valid input).